# Button disappears when clicked in javascript

Tags: javascript

In case that chosen attributes are the same, after clicking "Save button" - button disappears.
(it disappears from code, got deleted)

[Image before clicking][1]

[Image after clicking][2]

Most confusing thing is that, add button was coded the same but it works well...

I've got no clue what might be the case here.

Button:

```
<input type="button" height="20" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="return saveEdit()" value="Save" />
```

```
function saveEdit() {
    var elem = $('#Domain_Edit');

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Domain/DomainEdit",
        type: "post",
        data: elem.serialize(),
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.redirectTo) {
                alert(window.location.href = result.redirectTo + '?siteMessage=' + result.siteMessage);
            }
            else
            {
                $(elem).html(result);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            $(elem).html('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">' + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText + '</div>');
        }
    });
}
```

Code of button on page:

```
<input type="button" height="20" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="return btnSave('89515a0b-a671-4eff-a0eb-61c1d268f696')" value="Save">
```

```
function btnSave(id) {
            var elem = $("." + id).closest('#DomainTrust_Edit');

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Domain/DomainTrustEdit",
                type: "post",
                data: $("." + id).closest('#DomainTrust_Edit').serialize(),
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.redirectTo) {
                        // The controller action returned a JSON object with the redirectTo property
                        window.location.href = result.redirectTo + '?siteMessage=' + result.siteMessage;
                    } else {
                        // The controller action returned a partial view with the form and the errors so update of the containing FORM with it is needed.
                        $(elem).html(result);
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    $(elem).html('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">' + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText + '</div>');
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: You should add the code for `btnSave` as that seems to be the problem.

Comment: I'm looking for it rn, just saw that after pasting code here

Comment: When you redirect, you throw away the current page and state, and load a new one from scratch.  On the new instance of the page, with the new state, there is no save button, I guess.  Do you have code that runs on page load that sets the save button as enabled/visible?

Comment: Yes, on my DomainTrustEdit page, button was inside of IF statement(if both trust and trusting are not the same) then <input type="button" height="20" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="return btnSave('@Model.ID')" value="Save" />

Comment: After removing it out of IF, button doesnt "dissapear" anymore, also page doesnt proceed. All works fine.
Since I'm kinda new on stackoverflow, should I delete the question or update it with solution?

Answer (score 0):

Is your button located inside the `#Domain_Edit` element?

Since `.html(result)` replaces all html inside `#Domain_Edit` so if your button is inside that element, that would explain why it got removed.

Comment: That was my fault, I was looking for edit button in wrong cshtml file. (DomainEdit instead of DomainTrustEdit). Found solution, according to @James tip